# Android BLE code misbehaving on different phones

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have made an android app which connects to a device over BLE and reads or writes to the various characteristics on the gatt server hosted by the device.

While the same code is working on my Nexus 4 with android 4.4.4, the same is not on Moto G with 4.4.2.

On write of a characteristic I am expecting a callback on the registered BluetoothGattCallback instance, based on the status of which I have to continue on the flow. However, even though the BluetoothGatt class of android is writing the log for the write operation as status 5 (Insufficient Auth), the same is not getting propagated to the registered callback instance in MOTO G. However, the same works perfectly with Nexus 4.

Can someone suggest what could be the issue????

P.S.-I tried using the reliable write, but adding that stops the callback in Nexus 4 as well.